# How to Migrate WP7 App to Windows 8 Metro style app

Tags: windows-phone-7, migration, windows-8

I want to migrate my Windows Phone 7 App, to a Windows 8.

I started doing it after this Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465136.aspx

Those are the steps:

1. Launch Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Windows 8 and create a new Metro style app using C++, C#, or Visual Basic. Choose a project template that best matches your app layout and functionality. For more info, see Jumpstart your Metro style app using templates (C#, C++, Visual Basic).
2. Copy the folders, code, and asset files that you want to reuse in the new project.
3. In the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, click Show All Files.
4. Select the files and folders that you copied, and then right-click them and select Include In Project.
5. Perform a global search and replace to replace "System.Windows" with "Windows.UI.Xaml".
6. Copy the reusable parts of your original XAML code into the new project's XAML files, or into newly created XAML files as necessary. You can often copy and reuse the contents of page layout roots (typically Grid elements), but not the outermost elements (typically PhoneApplicationPage elements).

My Question starts at point 2: Let's say i have a page: Settings.xaml and Settings.cs. Do i have to copy both of them or none and add the code later? If I add Settings.xaml i get an error because of the tag:

```
  <phone:PhoneApplicationPage ...>
```

like it says at point 6.

I dont have any Problems with my dll's or with my "normal" classes, which arent connected to a xaml.

And when i create a Windows 8 Page i don't know where to add my Code from WP7 in Windows 8

```
 <Grid Background="Transparent">

  .....Code.....

  </Grid>
```

I hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with ColinE, instead of copying over all the files directly, create a new Windows 8 project and copy the appropriate XAML elements and C#.  If you've created separate supporting .cs files, those should copy over fine, but if your code is all together in a file, you need to figure out what methods to copy over and where to put them.

In terms of what kind of app to use (empty, grid, split, etc.) that depends on your application and its purpose.  Take a look at the Designing UX for Apps article to help figure out what will work best for your app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779072.

Here is another MSDN article that talks about porting a Windows Phone 7 app to a Windows 8 Metro app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465136.aspx

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest approach to tackling your XAML files is to create new usercontrols / pages in your Win8 project using Visual Studio. You can then cut and paste the XAML from WP7 to Win8 piece by piece. You can also copy across the code-behind during this process.

There are a few too many changes to make it possible to copy the XAML / cs files across directly.

Comment: thats exactly what i have done with my port. you copy paste chunks of xaml into the code and codebehind. fix in smaller bits as you go along

Comment: would you recommend an empty, grid or splitt app? or doesn't it matter?